# Getting error in ListFragments code in android

Tags: java, android

Hiii,
I am trying to show two lists on the same activitry using listFragment , but i am again and again getting the errors.

Here is my code for **FRAGMENT1.java**:-

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class Fragment1 extends ListFragment {

String[] items = {
        "cars",
        "bikes",
        "trucks",
        "bicycles",
        "scooters",
        "scooties",
        "Bullets"

};

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle  savedInstance){
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items));
}

public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v,
        int position, long id)
        {         
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                "You have selected " + items[position],
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } 

}
```

And my **fragment1.xml** file is:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ListView
    android:id="@id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"              
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is **activity_main.xml** :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<fragment
android:name="com.example.basicviews8listfragment.Fragment1"
android:id="@+id/fragment1"
android:layout_weight="0.5"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="200dp" />

<fragment
android:name="com.example.basicviews8listfragment.Fragment1"
android:id="@+id/fragment2"
android:layout_weight="0.5"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="300dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is my logcat logs:-

```
03-08 01:23:49.577: E/AndroidRuntime(1176): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-08 01:23:49.577: E/AndroidRuntime(1176): Process:  com.example.basicviews8listfragment, PID: 1176
03-08 01:23:49.577: E/AndroidRuntime(1176): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity     ComponentInfo{com.example.basicviews8listfragment/com.example.basicviews8listfragment.MainA     ctivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating     class fragment
03-08 01:23:49.577: E/AndroidRuntime(1176):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)
03-08 01:23:49.577: E/AndroidRuntime(1176):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
03-08 01:23:49.577: E/AndroidRuntime(1176):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
03-08 01:23:49.577: E/AndroidRuntime(1176):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
03-08 01:23:49.577: E/AndroidRuntime(1176):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-08 01:23:49.577: E/AndroidRuntime(1176):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-08 01:23:49.577: E/AndroidRuntime(1176):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
03-08 01:23:49.577: E/AndroidRuntime(1176):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-08 01:23:49.577: E/AndroidRuntime(1176):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-08 01:23:49.577: E/AndroidRuntime(1176):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
03-08 01:23:49.577: E/AndroidRuntime(1176):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
03-08 01:23:49.577: E/AndroidRuntime(1176):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-08 01:23:49.577: E/AndroidRuntime(1176): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
03-08 01:23:49.577: E/AndroidRuntime(1176):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
03-08 01:23:49.577: E/AndroidRuntime(1176):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
03-08 01:23:49.577: E/AndroidRuntime(1176):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
03-08 01:23:49.577: E/AndroidRuntime(1176):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
03-08 01:23:49.577: E/AndroidRuntime(1176):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
03-08 01:23:49.577: E/AndroidRuntime(1176):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
03-08 01:23:49.577: E/AndroidRuntime(1176):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1928)
03-08 01:23:49.577: E/AndroidRuntime(1176):     at com.example.basicviews8listfragment.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
03-08 01:23:49.577: E/AndroidRuntime(1176):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
03-08 01:23:49.577: E/AndroidRuntime(1176):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
03-08 01:23:49.577: E/AndroidRuntime(1176):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
03-08 01:23:49.577: E/AndroidRuntime(1176):     ... 11 more
03-08 01:23:49.577: E/AndroidRuntime(1176): Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Trying to instantiate a class com.example.basicviews8listfragment.Fragment1 that is not a Fragment
03-08 01:23:49.577: E/AndroidRuntime(1176):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:585)
03-08 01:23:49.577: E/AndroidRuntime(1176):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:561)
03-08 01:23:49.577: E/AndroidRuntime(1176):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4777)
03-08 01:23:49.577: E/AndroidRuntime(1176):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
03-08 01:23:49.577: E/AndroidRuntime(1176):     ... 21 more
03-08 01:23:49.577: E/AndroidRuntime(1176): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException
03-08 01:23:49.577: E/AndroidRuntime(1176):     ... 25 more
03-08 01:33:47.097: D/AndroidRuntime(1215): Shutting down VM
03-08 01:33:47.097: W/dalvikvm(1215): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3a58b90)
03-08 01:33:47.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1215): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-08 01:33:47.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1215): Process: com.example.basicviews8listfragment, PID: 1215
03-08 01:33:47.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1215): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start     activity     ComponentInfo{com.example.basicviews8listfragment/com.example.basicviews8listfragment.MainA    ctivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class     fragment
03-08 01:33:47.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)
03-08 01:33:47.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
03-08 01:33:47.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
03-08 01:33:47.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
03-08 01:33:47.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-08 01:33:47.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-08 01:33:47.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
03-08 01:33:47.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-08 01:33:47.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-08 01:33:47.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
03-08 01:33:47.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
03-08 01:33:47.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-08 01:33:47.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1215): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
03-08 01:33:47.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
03-08 01:33:47.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
03-08 01:33:47.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
03-08 01:33:47.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
03-08 01:33:47.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
03-08 01:33:47.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
03-08 01:33:47.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1928)
03-08 01:33:47.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at com.example.basicviews8listfragment.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
03-08 01:33:47.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
03-08 01:33:47.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
03-08 01:33:47.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
03-08 01:33:47.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1215):     ... 11 more
03-08 01:33:47.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1215): Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Trying to instantiate a class com.example.basicviews8listfragment.Fragment1 that is not a Fragment
03-08 01:33:47.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:585)
03-08 01:33:47.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:561)
03-08 01:33:47.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at     android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4777)
03-08 01:33:47.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at     android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
03-08 01:33:47.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1215):     ... 21 more
03-08 01:33:47.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1215): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException
03-08 01:33:47.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1215):     ... 25 more
```

My main_activity.java class is as it is . I didn't change anything in that class.

Can anyone tell me that wwhere i m doing things wrong?????

Comment: Post the code of your Activity as well, and make sure it extends FragmentActivity.

Comment: Thanks @Egor. I was extending only activity in the main class. Now, i used FragmentActivity and my code is working  fine now.
So, thanks.